# Missing Ant Global Tool Configuration in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ant

Why doesn't the Ant Configuration in my Jenkins appear under Global Tool Configuration?

See the image below:

[image]

There are only tabs for `JDK` and `Maven`.
In the other references I checked, there are others like `Git` and `Ant`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the [Ant Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Ant+Plugin) is installed in your Jenkins instance. Go to **Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins** and search for the plugin there under the **Available** tab.

Comment: Hi Sir @manouti , My Proxy Server Block that site where I can Update my plugins, Is there a way to retrive ANT in local repository?

Comment: @LKTN.25 You can install the plugin right from the Jenkins UI (you don't need to install it from the site I linked to). At the bottom of the page, there should be buttons to download and install the plugin and potentially restart the Jenkins server.

Comment: Sir @manouti, Thanks. It works. How can I put my build.xml in ANT Configuration in jenkins ? Im so confused in here.